# Recurring Transfer from S3 to GCS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket on S3 that I'd like to backup to GCS, maybe even Nearline. From my research it seems I could use gsutil running on GCE to do so. What I'm not sure about is how to make this a recurring transfer. Maybe once a month it would check the S3 bucket and move anything new over to GCS. Is this possible with gsutil?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing backup, I would recommend using `gsutil rsync`:

```
gsutil -m rsync s3://s3-bucket gs://gs-bucket
```

Unlike the `gsutil cp` command, this will only copy the diff.  If you want to delete items from the destination when they are deleted from the source, you can use the `-d` flag:

```
gsutil -m rsync -d s3://s3-bucket gs://gs-bucket
```

More information is available in the [gsutil rsync docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync).

Setting up a cron job to run one of the above on a daily/weekly/monthly basis should handle the recurring aspect.

Alternatively you could consider [Online Cloud Import](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/online-cloud-import); this is still in beta, but it would allow you to do the above without using `gsutil`.